# Xpath approach to use for multi tiered xml

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the following mock up XML. A tree with multi tiered ChildEntity elements and a Property value at the end.

```
<Root>
    <Family>
        <Guardian name="James">
            <EntityID>123</EntityID>
            <ChildEntity>
                <Name>Rita</Name>
                <ChildEntity>
                    <Name>Anna</Name>
                    <ChildEntity>
                        <Name>Tina</Name>
                        <ChildEntity>
                            <Name>Sally</Name>
                        <Property>
                            <ValueID>666</ValueID>
                        </Property>
                        </ChildEntity>
                    </ChildEntity>
                </ChildEntity>
            </ChildEntity>
        </Guardian>
        <Guardian name="Jake">
            <EntityID>234</EntityID>
            <ChildEntity>
                <Name>Anna</Name>
                <ChildEntity>
                    <Name>Isabel</Name>
                    <ChildEntity>
                        <Name>Tina</Name>
                        <ChildEntity>
                            <Name>Rita</Name>
                        <Property>
                            <ValueID>777</ValueID>
                        </Property>
                        </ChildEntity>
                    </ChildEntity>
                </ChildEntity>
            </ChildEntity>
        </Guardian>
        <Guardian name="Richard">
            <EntityID>456</EntityID>
            <ChildEntity>
                <Name>Michelle</Name>
                <ChildEntity>
                    <Name>Sally</Name>
                    <ChildEntity>
                        <Name>Tina</Name>
                        <ChildEntity>
                            <Name>Anna</Name>
                        <Property>
                            <ValueID>888</ValueID>
                        </Property>
                        </ChildEntity>
                    </ChildEntity>
                </ChildEntity>
            </ChildEntity>
        </Guardian>
    </Family>
</Root>
```

Based on the sequence (i.e parent-child relation) provided for Child Entity I have to derive the Property/ValueID text().

For example, if the input sequence is (Anna, Tina) - Anna being the parent, Tina the Child - I have to identify the node which has this sequence and then derive the property value. In above example it will be value 666 expected.

The input is dynamic in nature such that the it could be parent, sub-parent, child (i.e. 3 entities).

In such circumstances, I wanted to seek your advice as to what is the best approach to solve this problem?

The way I am thinking is iterative, 
STEP1: I start with Parent entity and get all nodes which has this entity
STEP2: Of the nodes selected in step1, check where i have the child entity

Is this an efficient approach? Is there any other better way to handling this?
Can a single Xpath query give me the desired result considering the dynamic nature of the input?

Your inputs much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Its difficult as you are saying you have a variable input. However in the general case your XPath will look like either of these:

```
/ChildEntity[Name="$parent"]/ChildEntity[Name="$child"]/Property/ValueID/text()
/ChildEntity[Name="$parent"]/ChildEntity[Name="$sub-parent"]/ChildEntity[Name="$child"]/Property/ValueID/text()
```

Unfortunately, XPath is a query language, and it can't make its own queries. But looking at the general pattern above, in pseudocode you'd want to do something like this:

```
List input; //e.g. ['Anna','Tina'] -> '666' or ['Anna','Isabel','Tina'] -> '777'
query = "";
for person in input {
    query = query + "/ChildEntity[Name='{person}']"; //Assuming some string formatting
}
query = query + "/Property/ValueID/text()";
document.xpath(query);
```